# A challenging trig identity

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that, for $g$ a nonnegative integer,

\begin{eqnarray}3\left(\frac{64}{75}\sin^2\frac{\pi}{5}\sin^2\frac{2\pi}{5}\right)^{1-g}\left(\sin^{2(1-g)}\frac{\pi}{5}+\sin^{2(1-g)}\frac{2\pi}{5}\right)=\sum_{p=1}^2\frac{4\sin^2\frac{p\pi}{5}}{5}\left(37+62\cos\frac{2p\pi}{5}+56\cos\frac{4p\pi}{5}\right)^g.\end{eqnarray}

I came up with this identity in my research and have a proof which I think is an overkill. I would appreciate any high-school level proof.

Comment: Let the common value of the two sides of the equation be denoted by $\ a(g).\ $ Then $\ a(0)=1,\ a(1)=6,\ a(g)=15\ a(g-1)-45\ a(g-2).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting to radicals,
\begin{align}
\sin^2\tfrac\pi5&=
\tfrac58-\tfrac{\sqrt5}8
,\\
\sin^2\tfrac{2\pi}5&=
\tfrac58+\tfrac{\sqrt5}8
,\\
\cos\tfrac{2\pi}5&=
-\tfrac 14+\tfrac{\sqrt5}4
,\\
\cos\tfrac{4\pi}5&=
-\tfrac 14-\tfrac{\sqrt5}4
,\\
\cos\tfrac{8\pi}5&=
-\tfrac 14+\tfrac{\sqrt5}4
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
3(\tfrac 1{30})^{1-g}&
\Big((5-\sqrt5)^{1-g}+(5+\sqrt5)^{1-g}\Big)
=
\\
\tfrac 1{10}&
\Big(
(5-\sqrt5)(\tfrac{15}2+\tfrac{3\sqrt5}2)^g+
(5+\sqrt5)(\tfrac{15}2-\tfrac{3\sqrt5}2)^g
\Big)
,\\
3(30)^{g-1}&
\Big((5-\sqrt5)^{1-g}+(5+\sqrt5)^{1-g}\Big)
=
\\
\tfrac 1{10}
(\tfrac 32)^g
&
\Big(
(5-\sqrt5)(5+\sqrt5)^g+
(5+\sqrt5)(5-\sqrt5)^g
\Big)
,\\
\tfrac1{10}(3^g 10^g)&
\Big((5-\sqrt5)^{1-g}+(5+\sqrt5)^{1-g}\Big)
=
\\
\tfrac 1{10}
(\tfrac 32)^g
&
\Big(
(5-\sqrt5)(5+\sqrt5)^g+
(5+\sqrt5)(5-\sqrt5)^g
\Big)
,\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
10^g
\Big((5-\sqrt5)^{1-g}&+(5+\sqrt5)^{1-g}\Big)
=
\\
2^{-g}
&
\Big(
(5-\sqrt5)(5+\sqrt5)^g+
(5+\sqrt5)(5-\sqrt5)^g
\Big)
,\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
10^g
\Big((5-\sqrt5)\Big(\frac1{5-\sqrt5}\Big)^g
&+(5+\sqrt5)\Big(\frac1{5+\sqrt5}\Big)^g\Big)
=
\\
2^{-g}
&
\Big(
(5-\sqrt5)(5+\sqrt5)^g+
(5+\sqrt5)(5-\sqrt5)^g
\Big)
,\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
10^g
\Big((5-\sqrt5)\Big(\frac{5+\sqrt5}{20}\Big)^g
&+(5+\sqrt5)\Big(\frac{5-\sqrt5}{20}\Big)^g\Big)
=
\\
2^{-g}
&
\Big(
(5-\sqrt5)(5+\sqrt5)^g+
(5+\sqrt5)(5-\sqrt5)^g
\Big)
,
\end{align}

as expected.